# add items from XML to arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have written the following code. However I would like to add the items from `characters.getData()` into a custom array as below so I can then use it to carry out mathematical graphing. How can I create my own custom array list containing `settDate`, `publishingPeriodCommencingTime` and `publishingPeriodCommencingTime`?

```
while(parser.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = parser.nextEvent();

    switch(event.getEventType()) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String qName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("settDate")) {
                bMarks = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("publishingPeriodCommencingTime")) {
                bLastName = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("fuelTypeGeneration")) {
                bNickName = true;
            }
            break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
            if(bMarks) {
                System.out.println("settDate: " + characters.getData());
                bMarks = false;
            }
            if(bLastName) {
                System.out.println("publishingPeriodCommencingTime: " + characters.getData());
                bLastName = false;
            }
            if(bNickName) {
                System.out.println("fuelTypeGeneration: " + characters.getData());
                bNickName = false;
            }
            rollingD subAction= new RollingD(characters.getData(), characters.getData(), characters.getData()); 
            break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
            EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
            if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                System.out.println();
            }
            break;
    } 
}
```

This is my custom class

```
public class RollingD {
    private String settDate;
    private String publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    private String fuelTypeGeneration;

    RollingD(String bMarks, String bLastName, String bNickName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public String getSettDate() {
        return settDate;
    }

    public void setSettDate(String settDate) {
        this.settDate = settDate;
    }

    public String getPublishingPeriodCommencingTime() {
        return publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    }

    public void setPublishingPeriodCommencingTime(String publishingPeriodCommencingTime) {
        this.publishingPeriodCommencingTime = publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    }

    public String getFuelTypeGeneration() {
        return fuelTypeGeneration;
    }

    public void setFuelTypeGeneration(String fuelTypeGeneration) {
        this.fuelTypeGeneration = fuelTypeGeneration;
    }
}
```

This is a sample of the XML

```
<settDate>2020-02-29</settDate>    
<publishingPeriodCommencingTime>09:55:00</publishingPeriodCommencingTime>    
<fuelTypeGeneration>31891</fuelTypeGeneration>    

<settDate>2020-02-29</settDate>   
<publishingPeriodCommencingTime>10:00:00</publishingPeriodCommencingTime>  
<fuelTypeGeneration>31743</fuelTypeGeneration>
```

..

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. Do you want to know how to create an `ArrayList` to store the instances of `rollingD`? By the way, you should follow the Java naming convention i.e. `rollingD` should be `RollingD`.

Comment: From the first line of the code in your question, i.e. `while(parser.hasNext()) {`, is `parser` an instance of class [SAXParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) ? If it is, then is the code you posted part of some kind of [ContentHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) ? Maybe you can [edit] your question and post a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash Its STAX rather than SAX. That is correct i would like to store it in an ArrayList. The while is from an API

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a sample XML that you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Abra I have provided below the custom class a sample of the XML which is repeated

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see any XML tags. Shouldn't that be something like: `<settDate>2020-02-29</settDate>` ?

Comment: @Abra I have updated for the tags. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @inky - You got confused between my name and Abra's name :) I didn't talk about SAX, it's Abra who has mentioned it. Anyway, let me check your updated question.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash apologies :)

Comment: No buddy...you don't need to be apologetic...these accidental things bring a smile rather than hurting anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my implementation according to how I understood your question.

I created the following XML file that contains only the sample data from your question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <settDate>2020-02-29</settDate>
    <publishingPeriodCommencingTime>09:55:00</publishingPeriodCommencingTime>
    <fuelTypeGeneration>31891</fuelTypeGeneration>

    <settDate>2020-02-29</settDate>
    <publishingPeriodCommencingTime>10:00:00</publishingPeriodCommencingTime>
    <fuelTypeGeneration>31743</fuelTypeGeneration>
</root>
```

Through experimentation, I saw that the effective order of the XML events is:

1. START_ELEMENT
2. CHARACTERS
3. END_ELEMENT

The elements of interest are:

1. settDate
2. publishingPeriodCommencingTime
3. fuelTypeGeneration

The basic algorithm is therefore:

- If event type is START_ELEMENT and event name is `settDate`, create a new instance of class `RollingD`.
- If event type is CHARACTERS, then set the value of the member in `RollingD` according to the event name.
- If event type is END_ELEMENT and event name is `fuelTypeGeneration`, add the `RollingD` object to the list.

Note that you need to replace *path-to-XML-file* in the below code with the actual path to your XML file.

Also, method `toString()` in class `RollingD` is purely for debugging purposes and therefore can safely be removed from the below code if you think you don't need it.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class StaxTest {
    private static final String SETT_DATE = "settDate";
    private static final String PUBLISHING_PERIOD_COMMENCING_TIME = "publishingPeriodCommencingTime";
    private static final String FUEL_TYPE_GENERATION = "fuelTypeGeneration";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader reader = null;
        Path path = Paths.get("path-to-XML-file");
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())) {
            reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(fis);
            List<RollingD> list = new ArrayList<>();
            RollingD rD = null;
            String localName = null;
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
                switch (event.getEventType()) {
                    case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                        StartElement elem = event.asStartElement();
                        QName qName = elem.getName();
                        localName = qName.getLocalPart();
                        switch (localName) {
                            case SETT_DATE:
                                rD = new RollingD();
                                break;
                            case PUBLISHING_PERIOD_COMMENCING_TIME:
                                break;
                            case FUEL_TYPE_GENERATION:
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
                        break;
                    case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT:
                        EndElement endElem = event.asEndElement();
                        QName qNamEnd = endElem.getName();
                        String endName = qNamEnd.getLocalPart();
                        switch (endName) {
                            case SETT_DATE:
                                break;
                            case PUBLISHING_PERIOD_COMMENCING_TIME:
                                break;
                            case FUEL_TYPE_GENERATION:
                                list.add(rD);
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
                        break;
                    case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS:
                        Characters chars = event.asCharacters();
                        if (!chars.isWhiteSpace()) {
                            String data = chars.getData();
                            switch (localName) {
                                case SETT_DATE:
                                    rD.setSettDate(data);
                                    break;
                                case PUBLISHING_PERIOD_COMMENCING_TIME:
                                    rD.setPublishingPeriodCommencingTime(data);
                                    break;
                                case FUEL_TYPE_GENERATION:
                                    rD.setFuelTypeGeneration(data);
                                    break;
                                default:
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Unhandled XML event: " + event.getEventType());
                }
            }
            list.stream().forEach(System.out::println); // Prints the list.
        }
        catch (IOException | XMLStreamException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (XMLStreamException xXmlStream) {
                    System.out.println("WARNING (ignored): Failed to close XML event reader");
                    xXmlStream.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class RollingD {
    private String settDate;
    private String publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    private String fuelTypeGeneration;

    public RollingD() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public RollingD(String settDate,
                    String publishingPeriodCommencingTime,
                    String fuelTypeGeneration) {
        this.settDate = settDate;
        this.publishingPeriodCommencingTime = publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
        this.fuelTypeGeneration = fuelTypeGeneration;
    }

    public void setSettDate(String settDate) {
        this.settDate = settDate;
    }

    public void setPublishingPeriodCommencingTime(String publishingPeriodCommencingTime) {
        this.publishingPeriodCommencingTime = publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    }

    public void setFuelTypeGeneration(String fuelTypeGeneration) {
        this.fuelTypeGeneration = fuelTypeGeneration;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                             settDate,
                             publishingPeriodCommencingTime,
                             fuelTypeGeneration);
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get after running the above code.

```
2020-02-29,09:55:00,31891
2020-02-29,10:00:00,31743
```